# Не работает сортировка в GridView Yii2 с MongoBD по связанному полю

Tags: yii2, сортировка, mongodb, activerecord

Имеется: Yii2 + MongoDb и две коллекции: StorageItems (товары) и Storage (склады):

Вывожу в GridView поля из StorageItems + [b]name[/b] склада по его storage_id из связи "storage". Ссылка для сортировки поля [b]name[/b] появляется но реально сортировка по полю Name не работает.  В чём ошибка? Очень прошу помочь! (перерыл всё что можно и попробовал все варианты какие только нашел...не помогает...)

**StorageItems (товары):**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Storage (склады):**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**StorageItems:**

```
class StorageItems extends ActiveRecord {
public function attributes() {
        return [
            '_id',
            'item_id',
            'storage_id',          
            'qty',...          
        ];
    }

public function rules() {
        return [
            [['item_id', 'storage_id'], 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
                    return new ObjectId($value);
                }],
            [['qty'], 'integer'],
            [['_id'], 'safe'],
        ];

 public function getStorage() {
        return $this->hasOne(Storage::className(), ['_id' => 'storage_id']);
    }
    }
```

**StorageItemsSearch:**

```
class StorageItemsSearch extends StorageItems {

    public $storage;

    public function attributes() {
        return [
            '_id',
            'item_id',
            'storage_id',        
            'qty',           
            'storage',
            'items'
        ];
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [            
            [['qty'], 'integer'],
            [['storage_id', 'item_id', '_id', 'storage',' items'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
   ... 
    public function search($params) {
        $query = StorageItems::find();
        $query->with(['items', 'storage']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

$dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
        'storage' => [
            'asc' => [Storage::CollectionName().'name' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => [Storage::CollectionName().'name' => SORT_DESC],
        ],
        ]
    ]);

$this->load($params);
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        ....
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

**View:**

```
...
<?=
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                [
                    'attribute' => 'storage',
                    'value' => 'storage.name',
                ],
          ...
          ]
          ]);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, нужно использовать 'content' вместо 'value', + нашел еще одну ошибку: в 'attribute'  нужно использовать не название связи ('storage'), а поле 'storage_id' и всё заработало!